# IntelliJ multiple text copy-paste options?

Tags: intellij-idea, copy-paste

In my project, currently I have to do a repetitive task, that I have two texts that have to be pasted interchangeably for quite a number of times. (Say '`Text1`' & '`Text2`')

What I am currently doing is copy '`Text1`', paste '`Text1`'. Then copy '`Text2`', paste '`Text2`'. Then again '`Text1`'. I am doing this tedious thing repeatedly.

Is their any tool which would make my current work easier.??

Comment: **[IntelliJ IDEA multiple clipboard YouTube screencast](https://youtu.be/srYR0Ut7ULo)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> for Windows/Linux 
Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> for Mac

It will show you the stack of latest copied texts (by default up to last 5). You can choose the one you wanted interchangeably completely without copying (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) again & again.

Answer (score 5):

[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is your friend.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/cutting-copying-and-pasting.html)

> Pasting a specific entry from the clipboard
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose Edit | Paste from History or press Ctrl+Shift+V.
> 2. In the Choose Content to Paste dialog box select the desired entry from the list of recent Clipboard entries, and click OK.
>
> The depth of the Clipboard stack is configured in the Limits section
>   on the Editor page of the Settings dialog box. When the specified
>   number is exceeded, the oldest entry is removed from the list.

Comment: Multiselect is also a friend.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something that is not IDE specific, there are many tools for that for different platforms:

- [Ditto Clipboard Manager](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) (Windows)
- [Multiple clipboard managers](https://superuser.com/a/17201) (Mac)
- [Top clipboard managers](http://www.tecmint.com/best-clipboard-managers-for-linux/) (Linux)